# Xamarin: app with two local SQLite database and Linq

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, xamarin

I am writing a simple Xamarin cross platform (android + ios) application and I have a doubt about how to manage SQLite in my app.

The app has a SQLite database (main.db3) that is the main database. I have declared a class mapped to the table of the main.db3 db with Sqlite-net-pcl library.

The app must download from a remote server, at intervals, another db3 file that contains the delta between the main.db3 local database and the database that is on the remote server.
So the app downloads that delta.db3 and takes the records in it and puts them, merging them with the records already contained, in the main.db3 database.

To access the delta.db3 I use the same classes I mapped to the main.db3 database, because the tables are exactly equal: only thing that changes from delta.db3 to main.db3 is the data contained in them.

I init the connection to the databases main.db3 database like that:

```
public class MainDb {
           public const SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags Flags = SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | 
                                                        SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | 
                                                        SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.SharedCache;
        static SQLiteAsyncConnection Database;            

        public MainDb()
            {
                Database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(MainDb.GetDbFilePath(), MainDb.Flags);
        
                if (!Database.TableMappings.Any(m => m.MappedType.Name == typeof(MyEntityModel).Name))
                {
                    Database.CreateTablesAsync(CreateFlags.None, typeof(MyEntityModel)).Wait();
                }
            }
    
    ...
    }
```

And I init the coonection to the delta.db3 database like that:

```
 public class DeltaDb
    {
    public const SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags Flags = SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | 
                                                SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlags.SharedCache;

    static SQLiteAsyncConnection Database;    

    public DeltaDb()
    {
        Database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(DeltaDb.GetDbFilePath(), DeltaDb.Flags);

        if (!Database.TableMappings.Any(m => m.MappedType.Name == typeof(MyEntityModel).Name))
        {
            Task<CreateTablesResult> result = Database.CreateTablesAsync(CreateFlags.None, typeof(MyEntityModel));
            result.Wait();
        }
    }

...
}
```

The problem is that at first run the app does not have the main.db3 created, because it will be created by creating an empty main.db3 db and then populating that with the data from the delta.db3, and after the delta.db3 connection is created, then the constructor of the MainDb is called and the line

```
if (!Database.TableMappings.Any(m => m.MappedType.Name == typeof(MyEntityModel).Name)) { ... }
```

prevents the line

```
Database.CreateTablesAsync(CreateFlags.None, typeof(MyEntityModel)).Wait();
```

from executing, and the table in the main.db3 database is not created. So the intert() into the main.db3 fails saying that the table does not exist.
I noticed that, in some way, the mappings (Database.TableMappings) are already there, as if opening a connection to the delta.db3 did some "global" mapping on the entire application.

So the question is: how can I avoid that? For sure I am doing something wrong with the initialization of the connections to two different sqlite database in the same app, but I cannot find any documentation to give me a hint of how can I do that properly.

That is my first Xamarin app and it's been two days of googling before deciding to ask here.

Thank you.

EDIT: I found that article I forgot to mention. But I don't know if it is still current. https://ericsink.com/entries/multiple_sqlite_problem.html

Comment: why do you need the check before `CreateTablesAsync`?  That method should not overwrite any existing tables so it should be safe to call if you tables already exist.

Comment: That is the same thing I was thinking, but the fact that the mappings are already there is making me wonder if anything is wrong about how I am initializing the dbs. Shouldn't the TableMappings for the main.db3 be empty the first time I open the connection? Why are they there? Are they from the opening of the connection to the delta.db3? It is confusing to me... And I wonder if that could lead to problems because my knowledge is limited and I don't find documentation about using two sqlite files in the same app.

Comment: I would expect the mappings to be empty - but if this is something you are testing repeatedly are you sure you're not just seeing an old copy of MainDB from a prior test?  AFAIK there shouldn't be issues with having connections to multiple dbs in one app.

Comment: I double checked, it seems that the "TableMappings" property is global for all the SQLite connections... So I think if I have a Class mapped to two different databases it could bring to problems, even if I don't know of what kind.

I would really like to know more about that. I just wonder how one could safely use two sqlite local databases in the same app. Anyone did that and have experience on that?

Comment: many apps use multiple databases - lots of plugins use their own local SQLite connection, independently of anything the app itself might be doing.  It seems like it would be simple to test reading and writing from two different dbs to verify that they were independent of each other

Comment: yes it is, and I did test reading and writing. It seems ok-ish, in the sense that I have to delete the line "if (!Database.TableMappings.Any(m => m.MappedType.Name == typeof(MyEntityModel).Name))" and it seems it works, but at the cost that I am not fully understanding what it is happening or if, with more concurrency than in my lab-tests, that could bring to problems.

Comment: as you noted yourself, TableMappings does not seem to be a reliable way to test for existing of table.  If that's what you need, you can query the master table in each db instead.

Comment: I think the problem is mapping the same class to two different databases. In that case, I think there could be overlapping with unpredictable results...

Comment: a connection only goes to one db.  All reads/writes happen via a connection.  I'm honestly not sure how TableMappings is used internally, but I fail to see how it could cause a read or write in the wrong db.

Comment: You have a class MyEntityModel mapped to the table "myentitymodels" of maindb. You read and write from there.
At a certain point, the class MyEntityModel is mapped to the table "myentitymodels" of deltadb.
What could happen then when, after that, the app wants to write again to the "myentitymodels" table of maindb?
That is what my fear is about. You say it is a useless question?

Comment: Maybe I should just make another class MyEntityModelCopy and map that class to the myentitymodels table of deltadb while keeping MyentityModel mapped to the myentitymodels table of maindb. 

Doing that no conflicts could arise. But again, not knowing exactly what is happening is not making be comfortable. Maybe I am too paranoic.

Comment: here is the [source](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/blob/master/src/SQLite.Net/TableMapping.cs) for `TableMappings`.  There is nothing in there that references a specific db or connection.  It just maps Table to classes.  This could be an issue if you had a class that maps to one table in dbA to a different table in dbB.  If you have a connection open to dbA there is no way that it is going to "accidentally" write to dbB on that connection.  I think you are spending a lot of time worrying about a problem that does not really exist.

Comment: If it would help calm your worry, post an issue on the github asking about this scenario.

Comment: thank you very much for you help, greatly appreciated! I think I will go ahead with development then I will go deeper on that as a matter of personal awareness. Thank you again!